# count and remove individual values of a single column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table and the values like this

```
create table items_table(url varchar(max),counttotal_urls int,countduplicate_urls int,Unique_urls varchar(max),
countUnique_urls int)

insert into items_table(url) values('ht,ha,hb,ha|hc|hy')
insert into items_table(url) values('ht,hb,hb|hb|hx|hx')
insert into items_table(url) values('hz,hy,hx,hm|hm,hy')
insert into items_table(url) values('hz,hy,hx,hm|hm,hy')
```

1. I need to replace `,h` with `|h` , for this I will use `replace(url,',h','|h')`
2. I need to count total_urls present by considering the separation `'|'`
3. I want to check or count how may duplicate url's are present
4. I want unique_urls to be updated in the Unique_url's column by removing the duplicates
5. Finally I want to count the Unique_urls which will be updated in another column

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: please paste required output as text

Comment: also show your current query attempt if any

Comment: please help me with the available code

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit complicated. But I tried to achieve it in Set based methodology.

Your Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE #items_table (
    id INT identity
    ,url VARCHAR(max)
    ,counttotal_urls INT
    ,countduplicate_urls INT
    ,Unique_urls VARCHAR(max)
    ,countUnique_urls INT
    )

INSERT INTO #items_table (url)
VALUES ('ht,ha,hb,ha|hc|hy')

INSERT INTO #items_table (url)
VALUES ('ht,hb,hb|hb|hx|hx')

INSERT INTO #items_table (url)
VALUES ('hz,hy,hx,hm|hm,hy')

INSERT INTO #items_table (url)
VALUES ('hy,hx,hm|hm,hy')
```

I have used several CTE's and XML methods

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT url
        ,REPLACE(',' + url, ',h', '|h') AS url2
        ,CAST('<M>' 
         + REPLACE(REPLACE(',' + url, ',h', '|h'), '|', '</M><M>') 
         + '</M>' AS XML) AS XML_FLD
    FROM #items_table
    )
,CTE2
AS (
    SELECT url
        ,SUM(CASE 
                WHEN SUBSTRING(url2, number, 1) > '|'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) / 2 AS counttotal_urls
    FROM CTE C
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT *
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
        WHERE type = 'P'
            AND number BETWEEN 1
                AND LEN(C.url2)
        ) CA
    GROUP BY url
    )
,CTE3
AS (
    SELECT C2.url
        ,C2.counttotal_urls
        ,SPLITS.ABC.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') DUP_URLS
    FROM CTE2 C2
    INNER JOIN CTE C ON C2.url = C.url
    CROSS APPLY C.XML_FLD.nodes('/M') AS SPLITS(ABC)
    )
SELECT url
    ,counttotal_urls
    ,counttotal_urls - (COUNT(DISTINCT DUP_URLS) - 1) AS countduplicate_urls
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT '|' + DUP_URLS
            FROM CTE3 C
            WHERE C3.url = C.url
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS Unique_urls
FROM CTE3 C3
GROUP BY url
    ,counttotal_urls
```

Result will be

```
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|        url        | counttotal_urls | countduplicate_urls |   Unique_urls   |
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| ht,ha,hb,ha|hc|hy |               6 |                   1 | |ha|hb|hc|ht|hy |
| ht,hb,hb|hb|hx|hx |               6 |                   3 | |hb|ht|hx       |
| hy,hx,hm|hm,hy    |               5 |                   2 | |hm|hx|hy       |
| hz,hy,hx,hm|hm,hy |               6 |                   2 | |hm|hx|hy|hz    |
+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Very elegant solution Shakeer  +1

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your work too @GouriShankarAechoor

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a string split table value function ([Found one at aspsnippets](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-function-in-SQL-Server-Example-Function-to-Split-Comma-separated-Delimited-string-in-SQL-Server-2005-2008-and-2012.aspx))
    as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

---

Once the Function is in place the below code can be used to achieve the desired result

```
;WITH cte_OriginalTable(url) as 
(
SELECT 'ht,ha,hb,ha|hc|hy' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ht,hb,hb|hb|hx|hx' UNION ALL
SELECT 'hz,hy,hx,hm|hm,hy' UNION ALL
SELECT 'hz,hy,hx,hm|hm,hy'
)
,cte_SaperaterFix AS
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID, replace(url, ',h', '|h') AS url
FROM cte_OriginalTable
)
,cte_Split as 
(
SELECT o.*,
    y.Item
FROM cte_SaperaterFix o
CROSS APPLY dbo.ufn_SplitString(o.url, '|') y
)
,cte_TotalCount AS
(
SELECT ID,COUNT(ID) AS counttotal_urls, COUNT(DISTINCT Item) AS Unique_urls, COUNT(ID) - COUNT(DISTINCT Item) AS countduplicate_urls
FROM cte_Split
GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT DISTINCT b.ID, b.url AS URLs, a.CountTotal_URLs, a.CountDuplicate_URLS, STUFF((    SELECT DISTINCT '|' + b1.Item AS [text()]
                        FROM cte_Split b1
                        WHERE
                        b.ID = b1.ID
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '' ) AS Unique_URLs, a.Unique_URLs AS CountUnique_URLs
FROM cte_TotalCount a
JOIN cte_Split b 
ON a.ID = b.ID
```